# Encountered Validation Error in double? datatype in MVC3 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, data-annotations

Hi guys I am new to Mvc 3 and previously while debugging my Project, I encountered an error in the field of `Miles` , and a very unusual error appeared that says `The field Miles must be a number.` upon entering `.2` and `135.` whereas it will be automatic that the value before and after the decimal point is zero, it is preventing me from saving the values and now I'm here searching for solutions.

I hope someone can help me with this.

This is my code snippet:

```
<div>
   <div class="label">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Miles) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Miles)
   </div>
   <div class="field">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Miles)
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my datatype in my Model:

```
public Nullable<double> MILES { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hm ... I thought that Nullable is generic type. Maybe Nullable<decimal/double> ?

Comment: This appears to be an issue associated with client side validation. Can you temporarily comment out the scripts and see if you still get the error.

Comment: @StephenMuecke After Commenting the ValidationMessageFor for Miles, the textfield turns red  that could be assign that its validated and the div have error class

Comment: @Disappointed tried changing the datatype in model but its exactly the same error showing in this field

Comment: @EnriqueGil, That means its the `jquery.validate.js` file causing the issue. Which version of jquery.validate are you using? (in recent versions I believe this was fixed). Note the relevant line of code (version 1.9.0) is `number: function(value, element) { return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(value); },`

Comment: @StephenMuecke just checked my `jquery.validate.js` and sad to say this is my current version `jQuery Validation Plugin 1.8.0`

Comment: @StephenMuecke is it also possible that the validation error that im encoutering is a built in validation of Entity framework?

Comment: @EnriqueGil, The current version is 1.14.0. But I'm not actually sure if its been addressed or not. The issue is that the regex for checking a number (as per my last previous comment does not allow `.` (dot) as the first or last character.

Comment: I am a little confused with your `while debugging my Project`. Is this error a server-side error or client-side as @StephenMuecke suggested ?